# How to communicate serial in a termux environment

Tags: android, node-red, termux

We are trying to implement functions such as Nextion Touchpad by building a local server based on Termux and mqtt borker of an Android phone.

I have installed the `node-red-node-serialport` pallet to communicate serial with Android phones, so I tried to connect my cell phone and FT232R USB UART with C to mini 5pin to receive signals.

However, it is not possible to search for "Serial Port" in `node-red-node-serialport` during this process. So the link below allows USB to search on https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Termux-usb
Termux, but it's still not searching.

Is there any way?

Comment: When you plug in the usb serial adapter does a new device appear under `/dev/` in termux?

Comment: @hardillb When you connect the four adapters, it shows that the device is connected on the termux.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question I asked. If you don't get a new entry under `/dev` e.g. `/dev/ttyUSB0` then you will NOT be able to use it as a serial port with Node-RED

Comment: When I connect the cable and enter ```termux-usb-l ``` in Termux, the output says "/dev/bus/usb/001/002".

Comment: We don't care about the output of `termix-usb-l` we only care about new `/dev/tty*` devices.

Comment: If I connect USB without typing any commands, there will be no response on Termux. It just says, "Do you want to connect to an app called ```Serial USB Terminal```?" (This is an app that I used to check whether serial communication was possible with an instrument)

Comment: As I have already said, if you don't get a new `/dev/tty*` device then you will not be able to use the serial port node. A quick search of the `node-serialport` repo suggests it may just not work on termux.

Answer (score 0):

There is a app on playStore called.
"Usb Serial Port IoT Gateway"
This worked for me.
The only issue I had was that I have to manually start the server each time.

USB Serial Port IoT Gateway is a Android app. It subscribes to your MQTT topic and relays the messages as RS232 signals through the Android devices USB port and external adapter.

Comment: You need to edit the question to explain how this works, as it is there's not really enough context here.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/ClusterM/usb-serial-telnet-server works for me, just install (available in github releases and Play store) and start it, then use a telnet shell app like https://github.com/connectbot/connectbot and start a new telnet session to communicate with other device.